# Play and Stop in One button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i'm newbie, i'm tried to make play audio play and stop for 1 button only, but i'm in trouble now.

if i touch a button when audio is playing, it doesn't stop, even playing audio again and make a double sound.

here's my code

```
public class ProjectisengActivity extends Activity{
    ImageButton mainkan;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test2);

        mainkan=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        mainkan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                go();
             }

            });

         public void go(){
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(ProjectisengActivity.this, R.raw.test);
    if(mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.stop();
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.seekTo(0);
}
    else {
    mp.start();

    }
```

i'm create for android 3.0 (HoneyComb)

Comment: Have a look on my answer, here i add a flag values, to check.

Comment: Try using toggle button instead of Button..

Comment: Each time you are creating a new media player instance rather than once....that is wrong !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code in go function....

```
public void go() {
  if(mp == null) {
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(ProjectisengActivity.this, R.raw.test);
  }

  if(mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.stop();
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.seekTo(0);
  }
  else {
   mp.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple, you should follow these steps to achieve this.

1. In your test2.xml create two buttons name start and stop.
2. Set the `android:visibility` attribute gone of stop button in xml file.
3. Now in your activity get the id of these two buttons and write the code for 
                 starting and stopping of media player.
4. Set the visibility attribute gone on start click and visible of stop button,
                 follow its opposite on stop click.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have wrong this line :

```
 mp=MediaPlayer.create(ProjectisengActivity.this, R.raw.test);
```

You create new instance every time user clicks the button, so it's never playing and starts again. Put this line into `onCreate` rather than `go()`

Answer (score 0):

Try also this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    int flag = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (flag == 0) {
                    Log.v("Inside if", "Success" + "");
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.raw.sample);
                    mPlayer.start();
                    flag++;
                } else {
                    Log.v("Inside else", "Success" + "");
                    mPlayer.stop();
                    mPlayer.release();
                    flag = 0;
                }


            }

        });
    }



}
```